Algorithm for adjusting formula excel from original cell to destination cell
I am trying to parse formula in excel with 3 params: Formula, original cell address, destination cell address.
Example, with some rules:



Formula
Original  Address
Destination  Address
Result  Expected
Note




=(A2+B2)
C2
C3
=(A3+B3)



=(A2+B2)
C2
D2
=(B2+C2)
Increase column by 1 (C->D)


=(A2+$B$2)
C2
D10
=(B10+$B$2)
The $ expression


=(SheetA2!A2+B2)
C2
C3
=(SheetA2!A3+B3)
The Sheet name(SheetA2) is invariant


=IF(A2=A3,A4,A5)
A6
C6
=IF(C2=C3,C4,C5)
Replace All variant



I know some library in C#, python ... did it, but now I want to do it in java. I need algorithm to parse formula to token and replace it, or a library do it fast.

@P.b What is your LET function?

=LET(a,A2,b,B2,i,$1:$1048576,INDEX(i,COLUMN(a)+1,1)+INDEX(i,COLUMN(b),2)) a and b are the cells you originally have. If you copy and paste it in a different column, the row index moves, but column index stays the same.

@P.b Its so hard for me to understand, can you explain more? with simple formula C1 = A1 + B1, how can I paste to C2 cell.

Another way could be to use =TRANSPOSE(range) and than reference the cells in the transposed range and it should behave like you mentioned, just in a different created range.

There is a Java library Apache POI, which is able to do this.
This library provides formula evaluation and shifting cells. So it needs parsing formulas and adjusting formulas to new destination cells. To do this, it provides FormulaParser and FormulaRenderer.
Of course those classes are programmed to do their work in an existing workbook. But if only the adjustment of formula strings is needed, then an empty temporary dummy workbook can be used. I use XSSFWorkbook in my example as this is the representation of current *.xlsx, which provides greater row count and columns count than the older *.xls.
Complete example testing your given examples and one more:
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;

public class ExcelGetAdjustedFormula {

 private static String getAdjustedFormula(String formula, String originalAddress, String destinationAddress) {
     
  CellAddress originalCellAddress = new CellAddress(originalAddress);
  CellAddress destinationCellAddress = new CellAddress(destinationAddress);
  int coldiff = destinationCellAddress.getColumn() - originalCellAddress.getColumn();
  int rowdiff = destinationCellAddress.getRow() - originalCellAddress.getRow();

  XSSFEvaluationWorkbook workbookWrapper = 
   XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create(new XSSFWorkbook());
  Ptg[] ptgs = FormulaParser.parse(formula, workbookWrapper, FormulaType.CELL, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < ptgs.length; i++) {
   if (ptgs[i] instanceof RefPtgBase) { // base class for cell references
    RefPtgBase ref = (RefPtgBase) ptgs[i];
    if (ref.isColRelative())
     ref.setColumn(ref.getColumn() + coldiff);
    if (ref.isRowRelative())
     ref.setRow(ref.getRow() + rowdiff);
   }
   else if (ptgs[i] instanceof AreaPtgBase) { // base class for range references
    AreaPtgBase ref = (AreaPtgBase) ptgs[i];
    if (ref.isFirstColRelative())
     ref.setFirstColumn(ref.getFirstColumn() + coldiff);
    if (ref.isLastColRelative())
     ref.setLastColumn(ref.getLastColumn() + coldiff);
    if (ref.isFirstRowRelative())
     ref.setFirstRow(ref.getFirstRow() + rowdiff);
    if (ref.isLastRowRelative())
     ref.setLastRow(ref.getLastRow() + rowdiff);
   }
  }

  formula = FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString(workbookWrapper, ptgs);
  return formula;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
  String[][] examples = new String[][]{
   new String[]{"(A2+B2)", "C2", "C3"},
   new String[]{"(A2+B2)", "C2", "D2"},
   new String[]{"(A2+$B$2)", "C2", "D10"},
   new String[]{"(SheetA2!A2+B2)", "C2", "C3"},
   new String[]{"IF(A2=A3,A4,A5)", "A6", "C6"},
   new String[]{"VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet Name'!$A$1:$G$1000,4,FALSE)", "F2", "F10"}
  };
     
  for (String[] example : examples) {
   String formula = example[0];
   String originalAddress = example[1];
   String destinationAddress = example[2];
  
   String newformula = getAdjustedFormula(formula, originalAddress, destinationAddress);
   System.out.println(newformula);
  }
  
 }
}


Oh, I see the code above have a temp workbook, what is its purpose, does it affect performance?

@cuong02n: "does it affect performance?": Yes , it does. If you would recreating the pure formula-adjustment-algorithm without workbook, then this will have better performance. But this formula-adjustment-algorithm is very complex and I don't know about any Java library that provides a such. I doubt even the libraries you found for C# and python are really complete to properly adjust all possible formula strings, except they work using a installed Excel application, which would affect performance more though. Apache POI not needs installed Excel application.

I got another issue, using System.out.println(getAdjustedFormula("_xlfn.XLOOKUP($A2,RAW1!$D:$D,RAW1!$R:$R,\"-\")","B2","B26")) return _xlfn.XLOOKUP($A26,RAW1!D:D,RAW1!R:R,"-"). But I want the adjusted formula not remove $.

@Nguyen Manh Cuong: "But I want ...": Then you will need another approach. This is how AreaPtgBase internally formats a full column reference as String. You can't influence that without fully reprogramming AreaPtgBase. For full row reference $5:$5 for example it rewrites that to $A$5:$XFD$5. But for $R:$R it does not. You would need to write $R$1:$R$1048576 in source.
